# font-smoothing not applied to buttons

Tags: css, button, twitter-bootstrap, webkit, antialiasing

I have used this snippet to prevent webkit from changing antialiasing when using CSS transforms:

```
html{ -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; }
```

This works fine for most cases, however I noticed some weirdness in chrome when playing around with Bootstrap using this HTML:

```
<button class="btn btn-inverse">John Doe</button>
<a class="btn btn-inverse">John Doe</a>​
```

This is how it looks in OSX/Chrome:

[image]

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hY2J7/. In fact, it seems that it is not applied to buttons at all. Is there a safer technique to trigger the same antialiasing in webkit for all elements?

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue. The text for both the `button` and the `a` looks the same as the right side of your image - OSX/Chrome 23.

Comment: @tw16 what OSX version are you using?

Comment: FYI as of 2023 I couldn't reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As the -webkit-font-smoothing is not a standard property, its inheritance rules are not properly defined.

In this case, for button elements, the default value for -webkit-font-smoothing is 'auto' not 'inherit'.

You can solve this by adding this css rule:

```
button {
    -webkit-font-smoothing: inherit;
}
```

Now, the button element should inherit whatever values you've set it to.

You may also want to run some other tests to see if any other elements also exhibit the same behaviour.

Comment: Your answer is nice and targeted and also explains why it works so I voted you up.

Answer (score 15):

[Your answer](http://jsfiddle.net/qrsf2/) is:

```
* {-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;}​
```

Comment: Oh man, you have no idea... I've been looking for this answer for months. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
.btn{
  text-shadow: 0 0.3px 2px rgba(255,255,255, 0.9);
}​
```

​

Answer (score 0):

There is a property named **webkit-font-smoothing** which can take value **‘antialiasing‘**, but… it will not help you with fixing font smoothing. While it should work on **Macintosh**, it will not work on Windows machines. The browser will **override** the property settings with its own configuration.

So, is there any way to fix this problem?
There is one trick that can make the fonts smoother. You will find the solution in the further content of this article.(That Article Link : http://kazymjir.com/blog/chrome-font-smoothing-antialiasing-fix/)

This problem can be easily fixed using text-shadow **CSS3 property**, which will create an effect which we can call **“fake antialiasing”**.

I hope this may help you to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this yet?

`-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`

I have it working in Chrome on OS X [in this update of your jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hY2J7/8/)